# How to add value of local variable in vector in recursion?

Tags: c++, vector, graph, adjacency-list

I'm solving a task about graphs and used this code (DFS) to add values in vector while walking in graph:

```
int matrix[N][N]; int used[N];
vector<vector<int> > list;

void dfs(int u){

    used[u] = 1;

    int i = 0;
    for ( i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
    {
        if ( matrix[u][i] && !used[i] )
        {
            list[u].push_back(i);
            dfs(i);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I read values from this list:

```
int size = list.size();
for ( int i = 1; i < size; i++ )
{
    int temp_size = list[i].size();
    for ( int j = 1; j <= temp_size; j++ )
    {
        printf("%d %d\n", i, list[i][j]);
    }
}
```

program returns me something like:

1 3473604

2 3473604

3 3473604

What is the problem? Please, help.

Comment: `list` seems to be empty. If you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it will be possible to tell if that's your problem.

Comment: Just this part is responsible for collecting values in vaector:
if ( matrix[u][i] && !used[i] )
            list[u].push_back(i);
But at the end when I read all vector, I get trash - incorrect values, like this:
1 3473604

2 3473604

3 3473604
But I must get something like
1 2
2 3
3 4

Comment: That's the bit you think is relevant. But without more detail it is impossible to diagnose your problem.

Comment: Have no idea which information you need)
I call dfs function from main, then go through vector in main to print values in it.
N is const that is max size of matrix[N][N] and used[N];
n is number of points I have, in other wors it is how many rows and columns I used

Comment: For a start, at what point does `list` cease to be empty? But if you just posted a complete example that showed the problem it would be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Your program has many errors:

to use

```
int matrix[N][N]; int used[N];
```

you have to initialize them with const:

```
const int N = 0, n = 0;
```

Can not use :

```
list[u].push_back(i)
```

because subscripted value is not an array (list)

same goes with:

```
list[i][j] and
list[i]
```

And

```
int size = list.size();
```

value of unsigned long may not fit into receiver type int as size returns int.

Comment: `list` is a vector of vectors, so `list[u]` is a vector (assuming `list` contains enough elements - admittedly a fairly big assumption here) so the `push_back` looks valid to me.

Comment: user has not provided any details regarding question, so that was my best assumption, but you are also right with your assumption.

Comment: Sorry, I have not written that N is const. But I think it is understandable that N is uppercase. So it doesn't matter.
The main problem, why i get wrong numbers in output? I push back value of i, but at the end I get trash

Comment: No problem, but you get the idea from answer above right?

Comment: No) Because list is a vector of vectors, so list[u] gives me u-th vector in list. And then i push_back(i) in list[u]. I changed int size to unsigned int. It gives me the same answer. The main problem is why vector doesn't save numbers I sent to him?

Answer (score 0):

Ohh) It is stupid mistake I've made. The problem was that I keep values in vector starting from 1. But in inner vectors, for example list[1], when i push_back(value), then this value is placed in 0 position, like that list[1][0]. So I need to rewrite my loop like that:

```
int size = list.size();
for ( int i = 1; i < size; i++ )
{
    int temp_size = list[i].size();
    for ( int j = 0; j < temp_size; j++ )
    {
        printf("%d %d\n", i, list[i][j]);
    }
}
```

int j has to be started from 0.
Thanks for everybody!